# Property 'scrollToIndex' does not exist on type 'FlatList<...>'

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'd like to understand the reason for this warning/error: `'Property 'scrollToIndex' does not exist on type 'FlatList<School>'`

I have a React Native Snap Carousel list that should be scrolling another list on snap.

I created a ref for the list that I want to scroll with `const schoolList = useRef<FlatList<School>>(null);`
The assigned the `ref` to that list with `ref={schoolList}`
And my carousel does this:

```
<BottomCarousel
  ...
  onSnapToItem={(index) => {
    schoolList.current?.scrollToIndex({ animated: false, index });
  }}
/>
```

The error I get is on this line: `schoolList.current?.scrollToIndex({ animated: false, index });`

So I did some digging. `scrollToIndex` [definitely exists](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/fd6cdb6097eb50a75caadd3d72df06a434d02238/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L4261) for FlatList.
What am I missing?